# SwiftUI: Background not bound by frame?

Tags: swift, user-interface, swiftui, layout

This is a conceptual question to better understand the workings of SwiftUI modifiers.

Suppose we have a `VStack` with a `Rectangle` in it like so:

```
VStack {
    Rectangle()
        .fill(.blue)
        .background(.gray)
        .border(.red)
}
```

Then that looks like:
[image: First code snippet]

The `border` surrounds the blue area of the rectangle up to the safe area and the background extends beyond the safe area. The official documentation mentions "By default, the background ignores safe area insets on all edges[...]" [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/background(_:ignoressafeareaedges:)). OK.

Well, if I frame the `Rectangle`, before the background is applied, I get a result that I find strange:

```
VStack {
    Rectangle()
        .fill(.blue)
        .frame(maxHeight: 200)
        .background(.gray)
        .border(.red)
}
```

[image: Second code snippet]

The `border` still surrounds the blue area, but the background is now framed, and doesn't extend beyond the safe area.

In my mind, since the `frame()` modifier was applied before the `background()` modifier, the previous behavior of the gray background filling up the safe area should be unchanged. What gives?

The closest answer I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73753362/swiftui-why-the-background-not-cover-all-frames-when-background-modifier-before) but it does not discuss this specific background behavior.

Comment: When safe areas are ignored, it doesn't change anything *unless* the view is actually in contact with the safe area along its full edge. If this condition is satisfied, then it will extend into the safe area if its `maxSize` permits. Otherwise not.

Comment: How would you expect it to "extend beyond the safe area" when the rectangle is nowhere near a "non-safe" area?

Comment: @BenzyNeez Interesting, that explains it, thanks.

Comment: @Sweeper The behavior is implicit in this example hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on my comment to your post, here is a more elaborate explanation.

For a start, it is useful to note that a `Shape` like a `Rectangle`  is greedy. By default, it will occupy all of the space available. The same goes for a `Color`. However, even greedy views will only extend into the **safe area insets** if this is explicitly instructed.

The usual way to instruct a view to extend into the safe area insets is to apply the modifier `.ignoresSafeArea` explicitly. But when setting a background behind a view, the modifier `background(_:ignoresSafeAreaEdges:)` can be used as a convenience. The default value of the parameter `ignoresSafeAreaEdges` is the `Edge.Set` `.all`, so the safe area insets are ignored by default. This is what you are using in your first example.

So, doing it this way:

```swift
.background(.gray)
```

is the same as:

```swift
.background {
    Color.gray
        .ignoresSafeArea()
}
```

(In the second version, the closure contains a `View` and not a `ShapeStyle`, so this is why `.gray` needs to be qualified as `Color.gray`.)

It is then important to understand that when a view is instructed to ignore the safe area and extend into the safe area insets, **it will only do so if it is actually touching the safe area insets**. If the view is not touching the safe area insets then instructing it to ignore the safe area insets **has no effect**.

In your second example, the `.frame` modifier that sets the height of the blue rectangle has broken the contact with the safe area insets at the top and bottom. The background behind the blue rectangle therefore doesn't extend into the safe area insets at top and bottom either, because it is no longer touching them.

However, the blue rectangle and the background behind it are still touching the safe area insets at the sides. So if you run the example on a device like an iPhone 15 and you rotate the device to landscape orientation, you will see that the background still ignores the safe area insets at the sides:

[image: Screenshot]

Let's now try a different example involving `Text` that fills the display:

```swift
let loremIpsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

var body: some View {
    Text(loremIpsum)
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .background(.yellow)
        .border(.red)
}
```

On an iPhone 15, it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

We can see that there is insufficient space to show all of the text, so it has been truncated with ellipses. But even though it is using the full height of the display and `.ignoresSafeArea`  has been applied to the content, the text does not make use of the extra space that would be available and the yellow background does not extend into the safe area insets!

The reason is the same as before: the text is not (quite) touching the edges of the safe area insets, probably because the line height for this font size does not use every last pixel of the available height.

The frame of the `Text` can be brought into contact with the top and bottom safe area insets by applying `maxHeight: .infinity`. The yellow background will then extend to the full screen height, even if the modifier `.ignoresSafeArea` is removed from the `Text`. This is by virtue of the default parameter for `ignoresSafeAreaEdges` that is being used to apply the background, as explained eralier:

```swift
Text(loremIpsum)
    .font(.largeTitle)
    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(.yellow)
    .border(.red)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Since `.ignoresSafeArea` was removed from the `Text`, it is still confined to the safe area of the screen. This is why it still doesn't fit, so it is being truncated with ellipses as before.

It is interesting to see what happens if the `.frame` modifier is removed and truncation is prevented by applying `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` instead:

```swift
Text(loremIpsum)
    .font(.largeTitle)
    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
    .background(.yellow)
    .border(.red)
```

[image: Screenshot]

The `Text` is now using more than 100% of the safe area, as can be seen by the proximity of the red border to the edges. This means, the background is again touching the safe area insets, so it is extending into these spaces.

Comment: This is an interesting and thorough explanation, thank you. Coincidentally, I was curious about text behavior next, and you have already done that in this answer, wow! In the snippet that applies `.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)` to the `Text`, I changed it to `.frame(height: .infinity)`, thinking this would give the same behavior, but it does not. With `.frame(height: .infinity)`, it seems that the background does not extend into the safe area, either. The explanation in Apple's documentation for these invocations is nearly identical, so curious why the behavior here is so different.

Comment: @septimyr Thanks for the positive feedback. Re. setting frame `height`, the value must be finite, which `.infinity` is not. When I try it I see an error in the console: *Invalid frame dimension (negative or non-finite)*. So I expect it is probably being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

As @Benzy Neez points out in the comments, the extension of the background beyond the safe area is determined by the frame's contact with the safe area.